# показать символы unicode без преобразования в эмодзи ☺ html

Tags: html, css, unicode

есть символ ☺, если его вставить без css стиля, то он отображается черно-белым, так как мне нужно.
А если он стоит на странице, где есть css стиль, то символ преобразуется в цветной эмодзи.
Я пробовал удалять части css, но только полное его отсутствие решает проблему.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно отобразить символ ☺ так что бы он не преобразовывался в эмодзи на html странице.

```css
.wrap {background: #EEEEEE; font-size: 20px; font-family: sans-serif, Tahoma; color: #333333; padding: 18px; margin: 1px;}
p {margin: 4px 0 4px 0;}
h1 {font-size: 20px; margin: 4px 0 4px 0;}
h2 {font-size: 20px; margin: 4px 0 4px 0;}
hr {margin: 4px 0 4px 0;}
input {margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; border-radius: 3px;}
form {margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;}

.line {background-color: #333333;}
.time {color: #EEEEEE; margin: 5px; font-size: 120%; font-style: italic;}
.text {text-align: center;}
.button {cursor: pointer; border: none; background-color: #EEEEEE; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: underline; color: #0000FF; display: inline-block; margin: 0.2em 0.05em;}

.border {border-bottom-width: 2px; border-left-width: 2px; border-right-width: 2px; border-top-width: 2px; color: #000000; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; padding: 1px;text-transform: none;}
.border_button {border-style: solid; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px; border-color: #333333; text-decoration: underline; }
a {text-decoration: none}
a:visited {text-decoration: none}
.grecaptcha-badge {visibility: hidden; }
.reCAPTCHA {font-size: 10px;}
.inp{display:flex;}
.mark
{
    background-color: #feeff4;
    border-left: 6px solid #e04386;
    color: #49152c;
    padding: 1px 2px;

}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .line {
        display: none;
    }
    body{background: #EEEEEE;}
    .wrap {font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif, Tahoma; color: #333333; line-height: 1.2; padding: 5px; margin: 1px;}
    h1 {font-size: 20px; margin: 4px 0 4px 0;}
    h2 {font-size: 20px; margin: 4px 0 4px 0;}
    p {margin: 4px 0 4px 0;}
    hr {margin: 4px 0 4px 0;}
    input {margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;}
    form {margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;}
}
```

Comment: Какая ОС, какой браузер?

Comment: вообще смотрел только с телефона iPhone, браузеры на телефоне safari, Chrome, Opera, FF. На компьютере эмодзи не отображаются, проблема именно на телефоне, но так же на телефоне без css отображается черно-белый смайл, как мне нужно.

Comment: посмотрел на андроиде, так же отображается цветной смайл